# Always allow install via USB on Xiaomi

Tags: xiaomi

So I'm trying to install my app on the Xiaomi Redmi Note 8Pro but there is a pop-up window that appears at the end of the installation with "allow the access". Is there a way to set "always allow" for this device so I don't have to wait for this window to show up and then click allow?

Thanks